# How can I configure my flash object so that it won't cover my other page components?

Tags: javascript, flash, z-index, wmode

I have this flash object that is being displayed in the middle of the page. The problem is that each time I try and open a js popup in this page, the flash object covers up the popup.

I've tried setting the wmode param to "opaque" and it didn't work. I've set it to "transparent" and still no change.
I've tried setting the "z-index" of the popup to a very large value but that didn't work. I've wrapped the flash object into a  and set the div's "z-index" to 0. That didn't work either.

Here's my flash object:

```
 <noscript>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="347" id="EditableTree">
    <param name="movie" value="<c:url value='${flashHost}/EditableTree.swf'/>" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="person=${id}&highlight=${highlight}"/>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<c:url value='${flashHost}/EditableTree.swf'/>" width="100%" height="347">
       <param name="quality" value="high" />
       <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
       <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
       <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
       <param name="flashVars" value="person=${id}&highlight=${highlight}"/>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
    <p> Adobe Flash Player version 10.0.0 or greater is not installed</p>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
       <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
    </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
 <!--<![endif]-->
  </object>
 </noscript>
```

Any ideas on how I can display something on top of the flash object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this param should do it:

```
<param name='wmode' value='transparent'/>
```

I see you already have it in one of your objwect tags

Comment: Yes, you're right. I used "transparent" but I used it in the <noscript> element. Higher in the page I had a <script type="text/javascript">
        var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0"; 
       ....
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ffffff"; If I add the "transparent" param here it works. Thanks